# Use of the conditional in past tense

Tags: traducción, gramática, tiempos-verbales

Hay una frase que quiero saber cómo decir en español:

> I arrived in New York. I **would be spending** the next few days there.

Aquí estoy hablando sobre una vez que fui al Nueva York, pero en la segunda frase estoy hablando sobre lo que haría después de llegar allá.

Mi pregunta aquí es: ¿podría usar el condicional en esta cláusula o sería mejor usar otro tiempo?

Por ejemplo:

> Llegué a Nueva York. **Pasaría** los siguientes días ahí.

Comment: *Tiempo* es la traducción de *tense*.

Comment: La explicación de la gramática se la dejo a otros que tengan tiempo de escribir una respuesta completa pero respecto a tu traducción sería mejor algo com "Llegué **a** Nuev**a** York, **pasaría/estaría** algunos/los siguientes días ahí "

Comment: Do you mean to say:  "IF I arrived in New York, I would be spending the next few days there."  This sentence is awkward this way even in English.

Comment: @Karlomanio you are right I changed the question to what I meant it to be. Thanks!

Comment: Está bien.  Donde típicamente veo este uso del condicional así es en en primer capítulo de ciertas biografías.  Yo personalmente odio este uso del condicional, pero eso es mi gusto personal.  Estarías en lo correcto.

Comment: Sí es correcto.  Otra manera de decir la misma cosa es:  "Estaría pasando..."  No creo que cambie el significado.

Comment: @Karlomanio Me parece que "pasaría" es mucho mejor que "estaría pasando". Coloquialmente, puede utilizarse el pretérito del futuro con "ir a": *... donde iba a pasar algunos días*.

Comment: Did you mean "I spent the next few days there" or "I was planning to spend..."? The conditional allows both possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ese uso del condicional en el caso que planteas es perfectamente válido. Si quieres que suene más literario, yo lo escribiría de la siguiente forma:

> Llegué a Nueva York, donde pasaría los siguientes días.

En palabras de la propia RAE, el condicional simple se interpreta como un "futuro del pasado" (de ahí su otro nombre: "pospretérito"). Esto se puede ver en frases como *Dijo que asistiría a la reunión*, en las que si se cambia el condicional por el futuro, la acción de *asistir* se interpretaría como posterior al momento del habla. Luego se usa el condicional para expresar una acción posterior a otra en el tiempo, pero sin orientarla respecto del momento del habla.

El uso concreto del condicional en el caso de tu ejemplo se trata en la *Gramática* de la RAE en el [párrafo 23.15r](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=weKoyblVvzqLIig,). Cito:

> Este uso del condicional [...] se ha llamado FACTUAL, pero podría denominarse también NARRATIVO, para equipararlo al imperfecto del mismo nombre. En esas oraciones no se introducen situaciones hipotéticas, sino hechos acaecidos. Al igual que sucede con el imperfecto narrativo, el condicional que se le asimila se usa sobre todo en la lengua literaria, en la periodística y en otros registros cultos de la lengua escrita:
>
> > <sub>Meses más tarde, eso se **convertiría** en uno de tantos dolores de cabeza para el empresario guatemalteco (*Salvador Hoy* 26/8/1996); [...] o el secuestro aéreo del congoleño Tshombe, conducido a Argelia, donde **moriría** después de unos años de cárcel (Alférez, *Políticos*); Al final el partido **terminaría** 2-0 (*Público*, 24/5/2008); [...].</sub>

Ahora bien, como su nombre indica, este uso del condicional es muy correcto pero suena muy literario, y no te lo recomendaría en el lenguage oral. Si prefieres una versión más sencilla, puedes usar simplemente el pretérito perfecto simple:

> Llegué a Nueva York, allí pasé unos pocos días.

Comment: Cabe notar que el condicional tiene un valor prospectivo (como futuro del pasado) pero últimamente tanto el condicional (dentro de narraciones pretéritas) y el futuro (dentro de narraciones presentes) han adquirido un valor conjetural, y por tanto se puede interpretar *pasaría cinco días* como *imagino que pasé*, *debió ser que pasé*, *pasé alrededor de*, etc.  Especialmente con el futuro, es el significado predominante en el lenguaje moderno